# Elixir phoenix web application broke after pushing to heroku

Tags: heroku, npm, elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

While trying to push my elixir phoenix web application to heroku I had quite a few issues which took pretty long to solve, but after I finally did... my application won't start anymore!

I'm still really new to elixir and phoenix and even heroku, so this is really a mystery for me.

When running mix phoenix.server this is my output:

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Phoenix.Template.hash/2 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:

  * hash/1

(phoenix) Phoenix.Template.hash("web/templates/error", "*")
web/views/error_view.ex:1: Dashboard.ErrorView.__phoenix_recompile__?/0
(elixir) lib/stream.ex:429: anonymous fn/4 in Stream.filter/2
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:3161: Enumerable.List.reduce/3
(elixir) lib/stream.ex:1433: Enumerable.Stream.do_each/4
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:1823: Enum.reverse/1
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:2581: Enum.to_list/1
(phoenix) lib/mix/tasks/compile.phoenix.ex:13: Mix.Tasks.Compile.Phoenix.run/1
(mix) lib/mix/task.ex:301: Mix.Task.run_task/3
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:1255: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
(mix) lib/mix/tasks/compile.all.ex:19: anonymous fn/1 in Mix.Tasks.Compile.All.run/1
(mix) lib/mix/tasks/compile.all.ex:37: Mix.Tasks.Compile.All.with_logger_app/1
(mix) lib/mix/task.ex:301: Mix.Task.run_task/3
(mix) lib/mix/tasks/compile.ex:85: Mix.Tasks.Compile.run/1
(mix) lib/mix/task.ex:301: Mix.Task.run_task/3
(mix) lib/mix/tasks/app.start.ex:50: Mix.Tasks.App.Start.run/1
(mix) lib/mix/task.ex:301: Mix.Task.run_task/3
(mix) lib/mix/tasks/run.ex:86: Mix.Tasks.Run.run/5
(mix) lib/mix/tasks/run.ex:54: Mix.Tasks.Run.run/1
```

Now, I don't really understand where this problem has come from and it seems very confusing to me and I would love some help.

I don't even know which files to share so you can maybe get some more information, but I'm willing to post any code in my project.

Comment: Looks like Heroku is installing an older version of Phoenix which doesn't have `Phoenix.Template.hash/2`. Does the app work if you clone the original repo and run `mix deps.get && mix phoenix.server`?

Comment: No, cloning the original repo and running `mix deps.get && mix phoenix.server` did not work. I am however getting a different error now: ```== Compilation error in file lib/dashboard/endpoint.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/dashboard/endpoint.ex:1: inlined function current_time/0 undefined
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:121: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue locally, and if you're working on multiple branches (which have multiple phoenix releases) ensure to rebuild dependencies, that might just be the issue.

Comment: This solved it for me: mix deps.clean --all && mix deps.get && mix deps.compile

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. In my case it was due to bad elixir and erlang version. I solved it by installing erlang 18.2 and elixir 1.2.3

I suggest using version managers for erlang and elixir (I used kerl and envex)